# What makes buttons purple in Android studio? Plus other odd behaviours for a newbie

Tags: android, kotlin

In web development, I see how tags have default themes defined in the browser, and I see how they're applied.

However, with Android Studio's themes, I'm really confused.  I can define my custom themes using `?attr/myClass`, apply it on widgets by `android:theme="?attr/yClass"`, and then assign a colour to that attribute in my day or night theme files.

But, what baffles me, is—that purple.  Where does it come from?  When I set the theme header to

```xml
<style name="Theme.TestingThemes" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

purples come for the *not night* mode.

- When I use other styles that come with *"default"* with Android Studio, I don't see exactly that purple.
- Some themes allow me to set my own colours, but some others don't, like the one that I mentioned.
- ***Worst of all that totally blows my mind is:*** when I open the theme files in `app/res/values/themes/*` and `app/res/values/colors.xml*`, I only see less than 10 themes defined.  ***Yet*** I see Android Studio suggesting to me a *long* list of colour names!  Where do these come from?

I only use [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) as my text editor. I'm drowning in Android studio. It's cool and powerful, but I require some baby-walking assistance.

Comment: "Yet I see Android studio suggesting to me a long list of colour names! Where do these come from?" Theme inheritance is at play here. Also it's kinda implicit sometimes and "Theme.SubTheme" means that "SubTheme" inherits "Theme" unless "parent" attribute is specified in the tag directly, then inheritance is explicit. And very often these types of inheritance are mixed along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default new project created in Android Studio has a `colors.xml` resource provided in the project (`res/values/colors.xml`), where the `purple_500` and `purple_700` you described are defined.

Any other colors and themes you see that aren't in your own project's files are in the AppCompat and Material Components libraries (defined as project dependencies in default new projects), or they're built into Android itself.

In the Projects panel on the left in Android Studio, if you expand External Libraries, you can see all the code libraries that are imported for your project as dependencies (these are defined in `app/build.gradle` and downloaded from the Web automatically). Among these dependencies are AppCompat and possibly the Material Components libraries, with their own provided resources within.

You can't modify the contents of the libraries. You're intended to customize by extending (making child styles and themes).

If you want to see where a reference is defined in Android Studio (in XML or other languages like Kotlin and Java), you can Ctrl+Click and it will jump to the line that defines it in whatever file it's in.

Comment: Will my APK file contain all those external libraries?  I guess APK is the thing users download from the Google Play Store.  Any tips on how to optimise my APK?  I noticed that there is an option to refactor the `External Libraries` directory, by removing the no longer used libraries (which makes me wonder: were these useless ones going to be distributed in my APK files if I hadn't clicked that refactoring option?).  I also wonder if there is a global refactoring option that deletes all the fluff that is not used in my code any more.

Comment: @caveman [See here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

Answer (score 1):

I've been developing with Android for a year and have honestly never bothered using [material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design) buttons.

You can create your own drawable file for the background of the button and then add that drawable to the back of a regular button in a layout. Don't let things like this frustrate you; there are so many ways of achieving the same outcome in Android :D

Comment: Well, it is bothering me.  I'm coming from a very minimalist Linux background.  I use Gentoo Linux, and compile my apps with custom `USE` flags.  Then, when I open Android Studio, all of the sudden, I get some _purple_ out of nowhere and gazillion variable names that the IDE is suggesting for me.  So I'd like to know at least some answers, such as, where are these many variables defined?

Comment: I feel you. The theming stuff in Android is actually a bit of a mess, you are right. If it is at all possible I would suggest you to start your project with Jetpack Compose, it is a new library for UI stuff in which Google corrected a lot of past API design mistakes. It doesn't have those themes/attrs etc etc. Otherwise I suggest you to have a lot of patience, read some guides on theme vs style distinctions (again, not relevant for Compose) and good luck. Android is a beast.

Comment: Interesting (re: Jetpack Compose being the liberator from this theming mess).  Thanks a lot.  Will give it a shot!